# pyspark join with 2 lookup tables

Tags: dataframe, join, pyspark

I have one sales data and product details in two lookup table

df_prod_lookup1

```
ID     product     description
1      cereal      Minipack
2      canola      bottle
4      rice        bag
```

df_prod_lookup2

```
ID     product     description
6      glass       bottle
8      plants      hibiscus
10     tree        banyan
```

sales_df

```
ID     product     
10     tree        
1      cereal      
4      rice        
8      plants
```

Expected output:

```
ID     product     description
10     tree        banyan
1      cereal      Minipack
4      rice        bag
8      plants      hibiscus
```

I am supposed to use lookup table 1 and later lookup table 2 if ID is not available in lookup  table 1

lookup table 1 and 2 are of different column names and can not be merged as one.
Is tehre a way to check if ID is available in lookuptable 1 and do the join if not then lookup table 2 for every record in the sales? Thanks.

I could do only simple join with one lookup table.

```
df_final = sales_df.join(df_prod_lookup1 on=['ID'], how='left')
```

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Left join first with lookup table 1, and then with lookup table 2.
The `coalesce` function allows you to merge the `description` fields.

```
df_prod_lookup1 = df_prod_lookup1.withColumnRenamed("product", "product1").withColumnRenamed("description", "description1")
df_prod_lookup2 = df_prod_lookup2.withColumnRenamed("product", "product2").withColumnRenamed("description", "description2")

from pyspark.sql.functions import coalesce

# Edit based on comments #
sales_df.join(df_prod_lookup1, on=['ID'], how='left')\
        .join(df_prod_lookup2, on=['ID'], how='left')\
        .withColumn('product', coalesce('product1', 'product2'))\
        .withColumn('description', coalesce('description1', 'description2'))\
        .drop('product1', 'product2', 'description1', 'description2').show()

+---+-------+-----------+
| ID|product|description|
+---+-------+-----------+
|  8| plants|   hibiscus|
|  1| cereal|   Minipack|
| 10|   tree|     banyan|
|  4|   rice|        bag|
+---+-------+-----------+
```

Comment: Actually I dont undersatnd why you are renaming product in the lookup table. I jsut have to check in the lookuptable 1 first and then if ID is not tehre, I have to check lookuptoable 2 to get the product and description and other columns from the lookup. Can you please explain? Thanks

Comment: You have same column names for all 3 tables. If I join without renaming, then the resultant dataframe will have **ambiguous** column names. If you can join both on `ID` and `product`, you only have to rename `description`. But in the question, you only join by `ID`, and hence I renamed the other 2 columns.

Comment: Thanks @Cena. That means, I have to change the columns names except ID should be changed right?

Comment: Thanks @Cena. But you are dropping only 'product1' and 'product2' when you join? Is it right?   join(df_prod_lookup1, on=['ID'], how='left').drop('product1')? I want to join on ID and take the product and description from the lookup.

Comment: Yes @Lilly , I was dropping the `product` fields from the lookup tables. I have edited my code to fetch the `product` and `description` from the lookup tables. Renaming columns avoid such name ambiguity.